# RSS reader: notify me on keywords

Tags: rss, newsreader

Is there any RSS reader software for Windows or even some online service like Google Reader, that will periodically check feeds and notify me through e-mail when some keywords are found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to filter RSS feeds by keyword.

A guide is available [here](http://webworkerdaily.com/2008/12/23/filter-your-rss-feeds-with-yahoo-pipes/). A video tutorial is available [here](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/3712899/10209148).

You can then use the output of the pipe with [FeedMyInbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) which provides 5 free feeds via email.

If you have more than 5 feeds then you can use Pipes to combine them into 1 feed as well as filtering.

Comment: I really hate watching feeds... e-mail is the only interface I would like to have. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Michael - I've updated my answer with an email service.

Comment: Everything is eventually coming to pipes :) I like the idea and also tried it, will use it for a while but if anyone else knows more natural way of doing this or any software I'll be happy to know.

Answer (score 0):

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/23671

Script Summary: 
Filters duplicated entries and unwanted content or highlight chosen content based on keywords (with regex support).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue except I primarily wanted *desktop* notifications, and I used a combination of [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) (for the notifications) and [Zapier](https://zapier.com/learn/automate-apps-examples/notifications-alerts/) (to hook up the RSS feed to Pushover).